# Can I download wow online

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My new laptop doesn't have a disk drive and I was wondering if I could download the game online without using a single cd
Ill have to purchase cataclysm and mop so I can play again 
Do I just use my key code on battle net and load the game on there

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

Just go to http://www.battle.net, and log in (or create a new account) and you can download any and all purchased blizzard titles without using a disk. This is actually a *better* way to install blizzard titles in general, as it often allows you to skip one portion of a tedious and drawn out patching process.